Why is it that probability density times interval width is equal to probability
In a discrete probability distribution, probability is defined as
$P(A) = \frac{\text{Number of elements in event }}{\text{Total number of elements in sample space}}$
This is very easy to comprehend, I mean considering there is an equally likely chance, if I wish to know how likely an element I pick at random is from event A, I just take the number of elements from event A divide by the total number of elements.
For a continuous probability distribution, I can't use the formula above because they are infinitely many elements to count, so I have to draw a probability density function graph which will depict the distribution of values across a range. The probability density function denoted by $f(x)$ represents the probability density at a particular point $x$. It's not a probability by itself but indicates how densely packed the probabilities are around $x$. $x$ represents the values that the continuous random variable can take.
Now this is what they say, the area under the curve of the probability density function graph will give the probability of the desired interval. From my knowledge of integration this implies that
$P(a\leq X \leq b) = \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$
Where by $f(x)$tells us the relative likelihood or density at point $$ and $dx$ represents the tiny interval around $$.
Now if we think of the PDF graph like a bar chart with very narrow bars, The height of each bar at $$ is $()$. The width of each bar is $$. Each bar's area, $() × $, represents the probability of the variable being within that tiny interval. As you sum (integrate) these tiny areas over a range, you get the total probability for that range.
Now the question is why is the product $() × $ equal to probability? I could easily understand the formula we use for discrete probability distribution, but this one $() × $  for continuous probability distributions why? or was it that someone just gave this formula without giving any explanation?

Even in discrete probability, “elements in A divided by total elements” is a simplified formula that doesn’t always apply. It is not appropriate as a definition. Was it really defined that way for you?

To expand on David K's comment: "elements in A divided by total elements" works when the sample space is finite, and all outcomes are equally likely. But it does not work generally in other discrete situations.

@David K I have edited the question

@paw88789 I have edited the question

Have you seen the exponential distribution? Have you ever discussed an unfair coin? If not, you have barely scratched the surface of discrete probability.

I think I get it since $f(x)$ will only be a probability density function if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx = 1$ and $f(x) \geq 0$. Therefore when you take $f(x)$ times the very small $dx$ you are going to get $0 \leq f(x)dx \leq 1$. Remember now that probability $p$ has the following property $0 \leq p \leq 1$, then the inventor said surely $f(x)dx$ can be used to give the approximate probability that $x$ lies in the range $dx$.
Another thing that the inventor thought of was that if we say $f(x)dx$ is the probability this means that the greater the value of $f(x)$ the greater the probability and the lower the value of $f(x)$ the lower the probability which is logical and true even in real world situations.
So I think two factors were considered in determining the formula for finding the probability.
$1.$ The probability p obtained obeys the property $0 \leq p \leq 1$
$2.$ The value of probability will reflect the reality in real world situation
This two factors are also used to determine the formula of probability in discrete probability distributions for equally likely outcomes given in the question above.
